# How i can add files to router?

Tags: php, routes, composer-php

I'm using [steampixel/simple-php-router](https://github.com/steampixel/simplePHPRouter).
I want to add image to index page. `/`
Image is in assets/img/name.jpg
How i can make assets folder public?
And should I add "public" folder?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why did you tag this with Composer? Are you sure your problem is related to Composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation you link to](https://github.com/steampixel/simplePHPRouter) recommends using [simplePHPPages](https://github.com/steampixel/simplePHPPages) as a framework.

It uses an [.htaccess configuration file](https://github.com/steampixel/simplePHPPages/blob/main/.htaccess) which says:

> ```
> # Deliver the folder or file directly if it exists on the server
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>  
> # Push every request to index.php
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
> ```

i.e. If a file is requested that does not exist, divert the request to the PHP router instead.

If you take that approach, you don't need to create a special folder to keep your assets in. They just need to have a place on your HTTP server and will be served normally if they exist.

Comment: What if i dont use apache?

Comment: What if you look for a solution for the unspecified HTTP server that you do use and which I can't help with because you didn't include that information in your question?